# Options for replacing damaged aluminum siding

Tags: siding

I removed an old pressure treated deck that was attached to my house this weekend. The ledger board for the deck was installed outboard of the aluminum siding. I had planned to replace the deck with a landing and grade-level patio. The problem is the siding now has holes where the lag screws were and the new landing will not be as large as the old deck. I'm having trouble locating siding companies who still do aluminum siding and pieces of aluminum siding aren't something that would seem to be readily available at a big box store.

What are some options for replacing the damaged siding that are less noticeable since the problem will be at eye level when the new patio is installed.

Notes:

1. I don't really have the option to grab siding from another location on the house.
2. New deck / landing will be as wide as patio door. I'm concerned with the siding to the left and right of the door.
3. Holes were temporarily filled with can spray foam to keep water / bugs out.
4. [image: Pic of exterior]

Comment: You are better off going with white - to match door there - if you cannot find an exact match.   The white will look like a trim line of siding and goes with a door landing.